# Setup custom role and role base module access Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I want to setup custom role and role base module access. and using this I want to set custom authorization to controller. I dont want to set fix (hard coded) role name with [Authorize(Roles="Manager, Admin")], The Manager and Admin role will be dynamic. Might be it is Sr. Manager or Administrator instead of Manager and Admin.

I want to implement this in Web API and MVC web. When user logged in that time system will get user's role and based on that roles user will be able to access modules.project.

I have attached screenshot of database and db script as well.

[image: i]

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblModule](
    [ModuleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblModule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ModuleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblRole](
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblRole] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblRoleModule](
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUser](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [EmailId] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUserRole](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRoleModule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblRoleModule_tblModule] FOREIGN KEY([ModuleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblModule] ([ModuleId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRoleModule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblRoleModule_tblModule]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRoleModule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblRoleModule_tblRole] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblRole] ([RoleId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblRoleModule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblRoleModule_tblRole]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblUserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblUserRole_tblRole] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblRole] ([RoleId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblUserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblUserRole_tblRole]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblUserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblUserRole_tblUser] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblUser] ([UserId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblUserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblUserRole_tblUser]
GO
```

Comment: Use Asp.Net Identity 2. Just create a new project and make sure that authentication is set to "Individual User Accounts" to see a basic implementation. Roles are automatically added to the user as claims. You can check user.IsInRole and you can add your own filter to secure the resource.

Comment: Ruard, thanks for response atleast. I dont want to use inbuilt feature. I want to do custom code. so I will thankful if you can provide some guidance or help on code level.

Comment: For authentication you can use Asp.Net Identity 2. Authorization doesn't have to be part of it, but it is possible to customize the model. So you could extend the model with your custom tables. tblUser, tblUserRole and tblRole are already part of it (you can extend the tables as well) and tblModule and tblRoleModule can be added. On login you can add the claims for roles and modules.